# Python ensure object appears at end of list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a Job class.  Here's a simplified version with some sample jobs:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
    def __repr__(self):
        return '< %s >' % self.type

job1 = Job('Copy')
job2 = Job('Delete')
job3 = Job('Scan')

jobs = [job1,job2,job3]
```

In my application, the jobs are added to the `jobs` list (from a db) somewhat randomly, but I need to ensure that any `Delete` jobs take place last.  The simplest way I can think of is to ensure the `Delete` jobs are moved to the end of the list, then the list is processed in order.  However, I'm not sure how to do that when the sort criteria is an attribute of a Class, and is there any guaranty that the list will be iterated in order when the jobs are processed?  Any advice would be great.

Comment: If you need a specific ordering, you could just use [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) and give the delete operation the lowest priority.

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado, don't need ordering apart from Delete at the end, but I'll check out heapq

Comment: I would try implementing a "process last"  stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jobs.sort(key=lambda x:x.type=="Delete")
```

The key will be `False` for "Copy" or "Scan" jobs and `True` for "Delete" jobs. Since `True` > `False` the "Delete" jobs will be sorted to the end

Answer (score 2):

Sorts are guaranteed to be stable, so just implement `__cmp__`:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
    def __repr__(self):
        return '< %s >' % self.type
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.type == 'Delete':
            return 0 if other.type == 'Delete' else 1

        return -1 if other.type == 'Delete' else 0
```

And sort the list before processing:

```
jobs.sort()
```

Comment: @JBernardo: Indeed it is. (Sorry - I appear to be learning Python from an eight year old book.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that shifts the `'Delete'` jobs to the end in linear time. It won't preserve order though. Using `sort` will probably be faster on semi-sorted data and shortish lists, but I thought I'd post an alternative since [gnibbler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354133/577088) beat me to the sort option (and did it better to boot).

```
def shift_delete_jobs(jobs):
    end = len(jobs) - 1
    for i in reversed(range(len(jobs))):
        if jobs[i].type == 'Delete':
            jobs[end], jobs[i] = jobs[i], jobs[end]
            end -= 1
```

Comment: +1 for linear option. Works similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11337242/174728

Answer (score 0):

I would make a job container class:

```
class JobContainer(object):
  def __init__(self, jobs):
    self.jobs = jobs

  def get_type(self, type, invert=False):
    return [job for job in jobs if (job.type == type) ^ invert]

  def get_jobs(self):
    return self.get_type('Delete', invert=True) + self.get_type('Delete')
```

And then use it like so:

```
jobs = JobContainer([job1, job2, job3])
print jobs.get_jobs()
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the `get_jobs` function would be great, as it looks somewhat nasty.